# UPDATE result of SELECT statement as if it were a view and display the result in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have a table `Table1`

```
----------------
| id |Col1|Col2|
----------------
|  1 | a  | 15 |
----------------
|  2 | a  | 25 |
----------------
|  3 | b  | 20 |
```

I'd like to create a new view which displays the exact same values as `Table1` except the Col2 values are changed to 30 if the corresponding Col1 value is a. I do not want to modify `Table1`.

How could I create a view that both UPDATES and displays the contents of this new table?

I can use pseudocode to demonstrate just the logic behind what I mean.

> var tableOneTemp = SELECT * FROM `Table1`
>
> UPDATE tableOneTemp
> SET Col2 = 30
> WHERE Col1 = a
>
> SELECT * FROM tableOneTemp

The view would then display the result of the final select statement.

Comment: Please tag your dbms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Case()` like below:

```
CREATE VIEW tableOneTemp AS 
    SELECT id,Col1,(case when Col1 = 'a' then 30 else Col2 end) AS Col2
    FROM Table1;

SELECT * FROM tableOneTemp;
```

Comment: You are missing quotes to surround the `a`. Then Change your "`var tableonetemp =`" with  "`CREATE VIEW tableOneTemp  AS`" and it will be a perfect answer